# While executing contracts functions getting out of gas error

Tags: polkadot, substrate-contracts-node, contracts, gas

I have deployed a wasm smart contract on chain using version `polkadot-v0.9.36`, after deploying the contract when I tried to execute its function i got error out of gas as shown below. [image: error]

When I tried the read function it was also not working as shown below[image: error2]

Can anyone help me with these errors?

Comment: I was about to post the same issue here. So it's only related to the UI and not the contract itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with polkadotjs UI, they have not yet implemented `v2Weights` completely in UI, instead use [contracts-ui](https://github.com/paritytech/contracts-ui/tree/master) to check the functionalities and interact with your contracts, which is working fine as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is problem with Polkadot.js itself, you can check this issue: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/8364