# Problem shibuya deploy contract

Tags: ink, astar, shibuya

I have tokens from faucet in Shibuya. I ran the command `cargo contract build` for `flipper contract`.

When I want to deploy contract using `Upload & deploy code`, I have `contracts.instantiateWithCode` broadcast but the contract is never deployed. It stays loading ! I can transfer, but not upload and deploy.

Can anyone can help me ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with polkado-js UI, so what you need is to use the [contracts-ui](https://contracts-ui.substrate.io) to deploy your contract and you can also refer to question [While executing contracts functions getting out of gas error](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/7366/while-executing-contracts-functions-getting-out-of-gas-error/7368#7368).